# Exception - non-transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was question: [Java+Spring: SEVERE Servletservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491093/javaspring-severe-servletservice) Realy thanks for help.I have another problem:

```
Jan 25, 2013 8:10:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/test] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:622)
    at pl.ivmx.contact.dao.ContactDAOImpl.listContact(ContactDAOImpl.java:25)
    at pl.ivmx.contact.service.ContactServiceImpl.listContact(ContactServiceImpl.java:25)
    at pl.ivmx.contact.controller.ContactController.listContacts(ContactController.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I change **return "/contact"** to **return "contact"** and i put `<context:component-scan base-package="pl.ivmx.contact" />`from **applicationContext.xml** to **dispatcher-servlet.xml** . Can somebody help me again ?

Comment: What about annotating `ContactController.listContacts()` or `ContactServiceImpl.listContact()` (or `ContactDAOImpl.listContact()`) with `@Transactional`? You must have `<tx:annotation-driven/>` enabled as well.

Comment: I add <tx:annotation-driven />  to applicationContext.xml and i have the same problem

Comment: And you added `@Transactional`? Your stack trace should be much longer with transactions enabled. Otherwise the annotation is ignored.

Comment: "@Service
@Transactional
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {...}"  Problem it's the same.

Comment: What is your hibernate configuration?

Comment: <hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>     
   <mapping class="pl.ivmx.model.UserTest"/>
   <mapping class="pl.ivmx.contact.form.Contact" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `<bean id="contactService" class="pl.ivmx.contact.service.ContactServiceImpl"> </bean>` in the servlet context - you should move your service class to the root web application context (where  `<tx:annotation-driven>` and the transaction manager are/should be declared).

Spring AOP-based/Bean postprocessor base tools like Global Method Security, Transactions, Caching, PlaceholderConfigurers(things that process `${..}` placeholders) work on per container basis. As the `ContactServiceImpl` bean is declared in the dispatcher servlet context, it's not being wrapped with a proxy, so the `@Transactional` is ignored.

In other words you should not place your DAO/Service classes into dispatcher-servlet.xml.

See [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)